# google index user profiles

Tags: apex, force.com-sites, community

we need to index the community site pages by google. we are able to index the static site pages by google but we need to index the dynamic pages (like user profiles, job postings which are created dynamically based on the query string ID).

Please consider following points.
1.  We have some user profiles, based on profile search from google it should display that user profile in google (similar to Facebook / linked in profile ).

Answer (score 1):

Google actually does index dynamic pages as well, I have seen that on my websites (not Force.com sites though). The trick is to ensure that you are complying with their indexing policies.

Quoting [this](http://www.feedthebot.com/dynamicpages.html) link which I've followed in the past for indexing best practices mentions 2 main considerations which should be kept in mind.

1. "dynamic URLs with a large number of parameters may be problematic for search engine crawlers in general, so rewriting dynamic URLs into user-friendly versions is always a good practice when that option is available to you"
2. "If you can, keeping the number of URL parameters to one or two may make it more likely that search engines will crawl your dynamic urls."

IMO, if your dynamic pages (user profiles, job postings) comply with above rules, they can get indexed by Google.